# esp8266 12E doesn't connect to internet

Tags: arduino, esp8266

This is my first Arduino application, and I have programmed it and learned on it.
It runs and can create a blinking app, and even by entering through Serial.

But when I try to connect it to the internet, it gives

> Fatal Exception 12

.

The board I am using is D1 Wemos (Retired). I am programming it using Arduino. I am currently running 1.6.8 version, but tried 1.6.5, and the same happens.

I tried to run the examples from `esp8266` library... they as well don't run. sometimes I get

> est Jan 8 2013 errors and then in the end wdt reset

but now, I get

> warning: espcomm_sync failed error: espcomm_open failed error:
>   espcomm_upload_mem failed

I am not sure what is the issue? any body that has an idea?

Comment: I've seen these kind of errors when I didn't provide enough power to the ESP. Are you by any change trying to power it from a FTDI module? The best way to power t I found is a separate poer supply and a LM1117

Comment: I tried to use the external power supply jack, and it just didn't work. I think the micro-controller is faulty, because I haven't found a logical solution to its behavior.

Comment: Don't open the Serial Monitor while the code is uploading. This is the most common cause for code upload to fail. 

 Looks like its the binary is not being uploaded at all. Nothing related to the actual program that connects to the internet..